# Get data where id with status on all specified dates

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Have a fact table joined with dimension tables to pull out specific information.
I want to pull out id's where the `status = running` and they must have the `running` status between several dates.

- If between the dates specified, the status changes to other than "running" that campaign is not counted for in the result.

I have an idea of how to approach it, but i don't think my logic and syntax is exactly correct. As I think the query below would pull data for 12345 which is not intended.

| iddate | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06-09 | 12345 | running |
| 06-10 | 12345 | running |
| 06-11 | 12345 | ended |
| 06-09 | 98765 | running |
| 06-10 | 98765 | running |
| 06-11 | 98765 | running |

The result expected should only show information for id `98765`

Current SQL

```
SELECT
*
From....
Where status='running' 
AND iddate BETWEEN DATE('2022-06-09') AND DATE('2022-06-11')
Group by 1,2,3
```

I believe I am likely missing a "NOT" condition somewhere to further filter out the dates.
Or the other thought is that id must have `running` between those dates, however, I am not sure how to apply that logic and its syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tag your rdbms (oracle, sqlserver mysql etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting those that had `status = 'running'`, you could filter out those that don't have `status = 'running'`, in the specified time frame.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tab 
    WHERE iddate BETWEEN DATE('2022-06-09') AND DATE('2022-06-11')
)
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM cte
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM cte WHERE NOT status = 'running')
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVBEV8biTQBfbQ7PZUZRQf/3).

Comment: It looks like this did the trick. So my understanding is that:
- I want to return the id between the dates. 
- where the id is not found, when i look for an id that does not contain "running".

And would the "NOT IN" clause basically "negate" all id's pulled from the subquery?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. In order to get the good ones, I'm looking for the bad ones and keep them away.

Comment: doesn't the inner query also need the date range?  for example adding (DATE('2022-06-12'), 98765, 'ended'); would not give correct results  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVBEV8biTQBfbQ7PZUZRQf/1

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing! @BryanDellinger

Answer (score 1):

you could do a case statement to compare the running count to the total count.

```
select id,
count('dracula') cnt,
sum(case when status = 'running' then 1 else 0 end) cnt2
from mytable
where iddate BETWEEN DATE('2022-06-09') AND DATE('2022-06-11')
group by id
having cnt = cnt2
```

here is the fiddle.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fmFcwnGXyovYezBSCQ4aac/0